# sending files to virtual machine SCP

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, scp

I am trying to transfer files over to my virtual machine

I tried the command

`scp files user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx:/home/user/directory`

I am later asked to enter the password for `user@xxx.xx.xx.xxx`

When I enter the password the output is:

`scp: /home/user/directory/filename: Permission denied`

I thought perhaps I don't have the correct permissions or rights to the files?

So I checked rights for each file and it is

`-rwxr-xr-x`

Not really sure what I need to do to correctly SCP my files over to my virtual machine

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions for the directory folder on the VM?

Comment: @mikea just checked and in my VM the directory permissions are `drwxr-xr-x`

Comment: and does user own it?

Comment: `ls -ld filename` --> `drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 13 18:37`

Comment: so that's your problem, it's owned by root. You need to change ownership to user or chmod +w it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `user` exists on *both* machines and that it has permission to write to the destination directory.  This means the destination directory must either be a) world-writable, b) writable by a group that `user` belongs to, or c) owned by `user`.

Comment: I'm not sure which number to use for these permissions. Im worried about "unsecure" permissions

Comment: Do this to make the destination directory owned by `user` and its group: `chown user:user directory` and do this to make it so only `user` can write to the directory: `chmod 2750 directory`.